# Fourth-order passive filter not behaving as intended

Tags: capacitor, resistors, circuit-design, ltspice, passive-filter

I have been designing a passive 4th-order RC low-pass filter in LTspice and was surprised to see that the slope is off substantially from what I would expect for a 4th-order passive filter. Instead of an 80 dB/decade slope, I am seeing a 40 dB/decade slope.

Any thoughts as to why this happens would be greatly appreciated. I have tried grounding at different points but it did nothing, which I expected.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably just a mistake in your reading/interpreting what you are doing/seeing. Perhaps, you were looking at the wrong node? Or perhaps you didn't allow the frequency axis enough span? (There is a transition region, after all, before the full effect takes place.)

Here's what I get:

[image]

Both curves (theoretical and simulated) are the same. Also, note that the slope is indeed 80 dB per decade, as expected. (Expand the image and note the blue line I drew parallel to the green slope.)

Comment: Ok. If that is what you got then it's clearly an issue with how I'm using the software. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something conceptual. Thanks for the help!